# Can I set mysql date default value to empty value?

Tags: mysql, date, default-value

I have a mysql table contains a Nullable date column with NULL as it's default value. I've tried to import 5000 rows data from a csv file which most of it's date values are empty. But those empty values became '0000-00-00' after imported to my mysql table.
Can I set the default value of that table column to an empty value? Something like '' instead of '0000-00-00'.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want NULL instead of ''?

Comment: I'm  using NULL now, but when I import data from a csv file, the NULL value becomes '0000-00-00' as described above.